# A regex pattern that matches all forms of integers and decimal numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I wrote a regex pattern which should (in theory) match all possible integers and decimal numbers. The pattern is as follows:

```
import re

pattern = '^[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))$'
re.compile(pattern)
```

How foolproof is this pattern? I tested out quite a few scenarios, and they all worked fine. Am I missing some edge case here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your expression matches numbers with digits before the decimal point but no digits after the decimal point, e.g. `33.`. Is this intentional?

Comment: You regex fails on exponential notation numbers, like `1e15` and `1e-15`

Comment: A regex pattern without a clear spec or sufficient unit tests to see what should get matched and what not, is impossible to review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression looks just fine, maybe we would slightly modify that to:

```
^[+-]?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))$
```

for failing these samples, `3.`, `4.`, for instance, just in case maybe such samples might be undesired. Other than that, you have some capturing groups that I'm guessing you'd like to keep those.

---

#### Test the capturing groups with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"^[+-]?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))$"

test_str = ("0.00000\n"
    "0.00\n"
    "-200\n"
    "+200\n"
    "200\n"
    "200.2\n"
    "-200.2\n"
    "+200.2\n"
    ".000\n"
    ".1\n"
    ".2\n"
    "3.\n"
    ".")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

---

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"^[+-]?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))$"

test_str = ("0.00000\n"
    "0.00\n"
    "-200\n"
    "+200\n"
    "200\n"
    "200.2\n"
    "-200.2\n"
    "+200.2\n"
    ".000\n"
    ".1\n"
    ".2\n"
    "3.\n"
    ".")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ljm5oV/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Ljm5oV/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: `3` is an integer, `3.` is a float value.  I would expect that latter string to match as well, so I would leave the `\.\d*` I modified.

Answer (score 5):

### Here's one:

```
number_regex = re.compile(
    r'^[-+]?(?:(?:(?:[1-9](?:_?\d)*|0+(_?0)*)|(?:0[bB](?:_?[01])+)'
    r'|(?:0[oO](?:_?[0-7])+)|(?:0[xX](?:_?[0-9a-fA-F])+))'
    r'|(?:(?:(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)?(?:\.(?:\d(?:_?\d)*))|(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)\.)'
    r'|(?:(?:(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)|(?:(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)?(?:\.(?:\d(?:_?\d)*))'
    r'|(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)\.))(?:[eE][-+]?(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)))))$',
    re.UNICODE)
```

### But seriously, Python numbers are complicated

If you really a regex that will match **ALL** valid forms of Python numbers, it will be a complex regex.  Integers include decimal, binary, octal, and hexadecimal forms.  Floating point numbers can be in exponent form.  As of version 3.6 all kinds of numbers can have '_' in them, but it can't be first or last. And integers > 0 can't start with '0' unless it's 0b 0o or 0x

From the Python documentation, here is the BNF for `integer`:

```
integer      ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
decinteger   ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*
bininteger   ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") (["_"] bindigit)+
octinteger   ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") (["_"] octdigit)+
hexinteger   ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") (["_"] hexdigit)+
nonzerodigit ::=  "1"..."9"
digit        ::=  "0"..."9"
bindigit     ::=  "0" | "1"
octdigit     ::=  "0"..."7"
hexdigit     ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
```

and here is the BNF for `floatnumber`:

```
floatnumber   ::=  pointfloat | exponentfloat
pointfloat    ::=  [digitpart] fraction | digitpart "."
exponentfloat ::=  (digitpart | pointfloat) exponent
digitpart     ::=  digit (["_"] digit)*
fraction      ::=  "." digitpart
exponent      ::=  ("e" | "E") ["+" | "-"] digitpart
```

Note that the '+' or '-' isn't technically part of the number; it is a unary operator.  But it is easy enough to include an optional sign in the regex.

To create the regex, simply translate the BNF into the corresponding regex patterns.  Using non-grouping parenthesis (?: ) and f-strings helps a lot (rf"..." is a raw format string).

Integer:

```
decint = r"(?:[1-9](?:_?\d)*|0+(_?0)*)"
binint = r"(?:0[bB](?:_?[01])+)"
octint = r"(?:0[oO](?:_?[0-7])+)"
hexint = r"(?:0[xX](?:_?[0-9a-fA-F])+)"
integer = rf"(?:{decint}|{binint}|{octint}|{hexint})"
```

floatnumber:

```
digitpart = r"(?:\d(?:_?\d)*)"
exponent = rf"(?:[eE][-+]?{digitpart})"
fraction = rf"(?:\.{digitpart})"
pointfloat = rf"(?:{digitpart}?{fraction}|{digitpart}\.)"
exponentfloat = rf"(?:(?:{digitpart}|{pointfloat}){exponent})"
floatnumber = rf"(?:{pointfloat}|{exponentfloat})"
```

and put it all together, with an optional sign, to get:

```
number = re.compile(rf"^[-+]?(?:{integer}|{floatnumber})$")
```

Which is how I got the regex at the top of this answer.  This has not been thoroughly tested, just spot checked:

```
tests = """
    0
    1
    123
    100_000
    1_2_3
    1000000
    1.0
    1.
    .2
    0.2
    3.4
    1_234.567_89
    0o123
    0b1111_0000
    0X12_34_ab_cd
    1e-10
    1E001
    .2e-2
"""
tests = tests.split()

for s in tests:
    m = number.match(s)
    print(f"'{s}' => {m[0] if m else 'NOT a number'}")
```